# Finding Opportunities from a List of Accounts

Tags: opportunity, account

I am given a list which has 1000 accounts. I am asked to find opportunities between stage0-5 that are present on these 1000 accounts.  I should differentiate these 1000 accounts into 2 ways.

1 If Account has opportunity which is in  stage 0-5, it should be seperated from the account that has no opportunity or opportunity that is in stage 6 or above. I need to differentiate the 1000 accounts into 2 lists so that we know which account has opportunity and which doesn't.

Your reply would be really of great help. Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to find them? Reports? SOQL? We need more information about the tools you have available and what you're tried so far.

Comment: I am trying to use vlookup in excell. If you know any better ways let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AccIDs=new Set()// fill this set with  account ids in your list
List=[Select id from Account  where Id IN (select AccountId from opportunity where stage='0' || stage='1'....... && AccountId IN AccIDs)];//this will result into parent accounts of  opp having stages 0-5.

Now  remove the obtained account IDs from the list of Ids you have to get the   the ones having  no opportunity or opportunity that is in stage 6 or above.

This will help you,just you need to modify  or construct your query.throw kudos if you like my answer !

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

1. Loop over all the Opportunities where Stage is between 0-5 and capture their AccountId.
2. Use [Aggregate SOQl](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) to count the number of Opportunities each Account is having. Something like this:

   `[SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) OppCount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId in: acctIds GROUP BY AccountId]`
3. Now, you can loop over the result to differentiate account where count = 0 and count != 0.

Please try and lemme know if it works.

Comment: I was trying to use VLookup in Excell, do you think that would work.?

Comment: That may work but i would suggest you to use apex.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use **roll up summary fields** to the accounts, and than make a **report** on the accounts filtered on the roll up summary results ?

Rather than receiving 1000 accounts, I'd ask for the selection criteria of these accounts, so that you can include these in your reports too.